# where can I find the .cpp file in CGAL?

Tags: cgal

I download the source code of CGAL in Github, but I just find the .h file,no .cpp, where can I get it? cause there is only declaration of function in the class of .h, but i want to see the source code of the function.
Thanks.

Comment: You have information in install.md on their github page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are almost no .cpp files in CGAL. It is a libary just as [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), that is it is **header only**.  This means that what you call "the source code" is template code which is in the header files. Sometimes you have to dig a litte bit deeper, that is the code is in another header files that gets `#included`.